# Windows 10 VPN - L2TP/IPSec With Certificate

Tags: vpn

I keep unsuccessfully connecting to a VPN and get the following message: The L2TP connection attempt failed because the security layer encountered a processing error during the initial negotiations with the remote computer.

I triple checked to make sure all of my login information, address and related were correct. I also made some changes to the adapter settings to allow different protocols. I am using CHAP version 2. Previous to the change in adapter settings, it failed anyway.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [this blog entry](https://tycoonrp.wordpress.com/2018/09/11/the-l2tp-connection-attempt-failed-because-the-security-layer-encountered-a-processing-error-during-initial-negotiations-with-the-remote-computer/) could help.  #3 below fixed this issue for me:

- Incorrect pre-shared key:
  Solution: Ensure that the pre-shared secret is configured correctly on the client machine. It must match between the MX and the client.
- Firewall blocking VPN traffic to MX:
  Solution: Ensure UDP ports 500 (IKE) and 4500 (IPsec NAT-T) are being forwarded to the MX and not blocked. If traffic cannot reach the MX on these ports, the connection will timeout and fail.
- IKE and AuthIP IPsec Keying Modules disabled:
  Solution: This occurs most often when 3rd party VPN software has been installed and disables the IKEEXT service. This can be re-enabled by navigating in Windows to Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Services. Find the service named “IKE and AuthIP IPsec Keying Modules” and open it. Change the Startup type to “Automatic”. it may be necessary to remove the 3rd party VPN software.

In my case, I didn't have to uninstall any third party VPN software.